# Отправка формы по кнопке enter и по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как реализовать авторизацию и по enter и по клику?

Вот сама кнопка, только сделана через ссылку

```
<a href="#" class="regpopup_content_form_submit" id="submit_button_aut_user"><?=GetMessage("AUTH_LOGIN_BUTTON")?></a>
```

js код

```
// авторизация пользователя и вывод ошибок
    document.getElementById('submit_button_aut_user').onclick  = function(){
      let login = document.getElementById('user_aut_login').value
      let password  = document.getElementById('user_aut_pass').value          
      var res = getAutorisation(login, password).then(function(data) {
            $result = JSON.parse(data);
            if($result['TYPE']=='ERROR'){
                document.getElementById('message_error_aut').innerHTML = '&#8226; '+$result['VALUE'];
            }
            if($result['TYPE']=='SUCCES'){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```js
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    this.submit();
  } 
})
```

```html
<form id="myform">
<input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Задал id форме, и обратился как вы описали. Нажатие не видит

Comment: @ГригорийМытарев ну видимо где-то что-то напутали. Даже в представленном мной примере работает

Comment: по сути то нечего путать, только id свой подставить)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var password  = document.getElementById('user_aut_pass');

password.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){

    var subm = document.getElementById('submit_button_aut_user');

    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        subm.click();
        console.log('succ');
    }

})
```

```html
<input id="user_aut_pass" type="text">

<a id="submit_button_aut_user" href="">subm</a>
```

может поставить прослушку на события нажатия кнопки( если она не в форме) ?
document.getElementById('user_aut_pass').value (это ведь инпут ?)
и написать такую же функцию

Comment: Странное решение )) В том плане что вызывать onClick по ссылке при keydown в поле. К тому же еще и вешать событие придется не на одно поле, а как минимум еще и на логин.

Comment: ссылка-кнопка находится в форме, пароль и логин в инпуте.
Я пробовал снимать событие клика с верхней функции и просто вызывать ее по имени по клику и по enter. Но не пошло, поэтому сюда написал

Comment: погоди, раз ссылка в форме - так почему бы ее не переделать в button type="submit", и уже под это дело пилить события ?

Comment: Я пока не понял зачем было сделано по ссылке, думаю пока лучше не переделывать

Comment: а чего боятся ? посмотри события на эту кнопку

Comment: В общем, сделал просто такую кнопку, только инпут сабмит. Работает по enter и по клику. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка авторизации все равно ведь в форме будет.
Если фокус в полях формы, то при нажатии "Enter" и так будет происходить submit.
Просто обработчик клика кнопки добавьте и на форму.

```
<form id="auth_form">
  ...Поля формы

  <a href="#" class="regpopup_content_form_submit" id="submit_button_aut_user">
    <?=GetMessage("AUTH_LOGIN_BUTTON")?>
  </a>
</form>
```

```
function handleForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  ...Ваш код обработки
}
```

```
$('#auth_form').on('submit', handleForm)
$('#auth_form #submit_button_aut_user').on('click', handleForm)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button_aut_user" class="regpopup_content_form_submit" value="<?=GetMessage("AUTH_LOGIN_BUTTON")?>" />
```

Просто заменил кнопку-ссылку на нормальный инпут, теперь авторизация идет и по клику и по Enter